# Can the definite integral of a real valued function be a complex number with imaginary part?

Tags: calculus, integration

While working on an engineering problem I needed to calculate this integral, so I typed it into the Wolfram Alpha and got this:

[image]

If you look at the logarithms, you will see that one of arguments have the opposite sign than the other. This means logarithms with negative arguments there, which means the result will definitely have imaginary terms. Why?

It doesn't look like there is a way to cancel the imaginary terms when I calculate a definite integral, but I think it's definitely possible to set 
the parameters and the range so the integrand remains real: large $a$, large $c$, small $b$ and the range of $x$ is around 0.

Comment: I think it just means the "$+$ constant" is a nonreal constant.

Comment: what is weird is that in wolfram $\text{Integrate  Re[ ln(2*sqrt(a)*sqrt(a*x^2-b*x+c)+2*a*x-b)]}$ yields "no result" while $\text{Re[Integrate ln(2*sqrt(a)*sqrt(a*x^2-b*x+c)+2*a*x-b)]}$ yields $\text{Re[f(x)]}$ where $f$ is the function above

Comment: Your function is not only real valued. With x=0 and c<0 you have a root out of a negative value there.

Comment: @Diego of course it's not real valued everywhere. But the question ask why does it seem to give a complex number with an imaginary part when I perform a definite integral on a range where it remains real.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But when I calculate a definite integral that constant vanishes anyway...

Comment: Your formula is for an indefinite integral, isn't it?

Comment: @Diego Yes but can you show me that the imaginary part vanishes when you perform the integral on the real valued part?

Comment: If you ask me you should rewrite your question, look up the definition of definite and indefinite integrals and the criteria of their existence. My intuition tells me that because your function is not defined in all of R you can not expect it to have an indefinite integral in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from the already mentioned fact that
$$
\ln(-a)=\ln(a)\pm i\pi
$$
you can directly simplify the integral as
$$
I=\int\ln\left(\sqrt{(2ax-b)^2+4ac-b^2}+(2ax-b)\right) dx
\\=\frac1{2a}\int\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right) du
$$
which has a decided resemblance to the Arsinh function. This suggests to look at
$$
\frac{d}{du}u·\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right)
=
\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right)+u·\frac{\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+d}}+1}{\sqrt{u^2+d}+u}
\\=
\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right)+\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+d}}
$$
(this is partial integration backwards), so that
$$
\int\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right) du
=
u·\ln\left(\sqrt{u^2+d}+u\right) - \sqrt{u^2+d} + C
$$

---

Inserting this backwards gets one
$$
I = \frac{2ax-b}{2a}·\ln\left(\sqrt{4a(ax^2-bx+c)}+2ax-b\right) - \frac1{2a}·\sqrt{4a(ax^2-bx+c)} + C
$$
which up to variations of $\sqrt{4a}=2\sqrt{a}$ is the same anti-derivative as the one from WA.

Comment: If you can show me that this indefinite integral is equal to the one given by the Wolfram Alpha, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Of course, you only need to insert backwards.